# jQuery find not working on ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, find

I am trying to find specific elements with class .resultxx, the class is read from  database by a php script and injected into the  target element in the called file, but the result I get is [object Object], here is the code for clarity, what am I doing wrong.

a)The called file(lib/script.php) get data from the database and echo the list through the while loop

```
<?php while($results->fetch()){ ?>

<div  class="outer-div">
 <div  class="list-group-item <?=$media_list;?>">
   <div class="media-left">
    Etiam ipsum ex, iaculis non egestas nec, facilisis quis ligula.
    malesuada est, vel malesuada tortor varius imperdiet. 
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

b)The calling file get the result from the called file and find the specific selector to be viewed

```
<div>
<script>
 var url = 'lib/script.php';

 $.ajax({
  url: url, 
  cache: false,
  success: function(response) {
  var result = $(response).find(".result1");
  alert(result); 
 }
});
</script>
</div>
```

I have searched all through like 3 days and tried some suggestion I have found here including wrapping the  targeted element in a div but it's not working.

Comment: did u try to inspect the response?

Comment: `alert` is not a debugging tool. Use `console.log` instead. `[object Object]` is the default **string representation** of objects.

Comment: Yeah, I have use console but it prints nothing, I know alert is not a debugging tool but using it doesn't diminish the purpose of trouble shooting.

Comment: Yeah, the response is working fine.